# How do you understand "job ranking" and/or "jobs ranking"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, translation, interpretation

There's a publication that my company's translating from Polish into English that describes how Polish people perceive different occupations in terms of social importance, female/male character, etc. The translator chose to translate the title as "Jobs ranking" (the word ranking was used in Polish, too, I guess it's because of marketing reasons).

Would you say it's an adequate title? Is it correct? How would a native speaker understand "jobs ranking"?

Comment: Questions about tittle is off topic in this site. If I not mistaken.

Comment: To help you: the ranking of jobs=jobs' ranking OR job ranking. The latter is an attributive use of the noun. Choose one and stick to it. BUT as a title, one might use: "The Ranking of Jobs in Poland and Social Perception"

Comment: @user1176409 I appreciate your suggested edits for tag wikis, but they have a typo in them (use instead of used). I would probably write "This tag is for questions..." to match some of the other tag wikis. Unfortunately that queue doesn't let me improve the edit like it does with other posts.

Comment: Hello Milena. This site is for questions about *learning* English. Proofreading is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be:

*Occupation Ratings: ______________________*

where the blank would be filled in with a very terse descriptive phrase, such as "Polish Perceptions of Social Value"